# ReactJS- server side rendering without prefetching API response in server.js

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

In a React app, I need to call APIs server-side without `server.js` being aware of which APIs to call. The API calls should be encapsulated within the app's source code, and when server-side rendering is enabled, the APIs should be called internally prior to UI rendering.

I have tried the following:

1. Using `fetch` in `server.js` and then rendering the app passing data. This is not a viable solution for my case.
2. Using `unsafe_componentWillMount()`, which is the only lifecycle method that is supposed to be called on server rendering. I also tried using `getDerivedState`, but both call the API from the browser rather than on the server.